# SQL Query Not working - Aggregations and Join

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm currently running the SQL query below in AWS (Redshift, accessed through SQL Workbench) and getting this error:

> Invalid input syntax for type numeric. code: 8001

What am I doing wrong? Thank you so much for any help you can provide!

The query that fails:

```
SELECT  
    b.description,
    a.date,
    SUM(a.time1_sec),
    SUM(a.time2_sec),
    SUM(a.time3_sec),
    SUM(a.time4_sec),
    SUM(a.time5_sec),
    COUNT(DISTINCT(a.id))
FROM 
    a 
JOIN 
    b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE 
    a.date >= '2014-01-01'
    AND b.date <= '2019-07-31'
GROUP BY 
    a.date, b.description
```

Two queries that work:

```
SELECT 
    a.date,
    SUM(a.time1_sec),
    SUM(a.time2_sec),
    SUM(a.time3_sec),
    SUM(a.time4_sec),
    SUM(a.time5_sec),
    COUNT(DISTINCT(a.id))
FROM
    a 
JOIN 
    b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE 
    a.date >= '2014-01-01'
    AND b.date <= '2019-07-31'
GROUP BY 
    a.date
```

This also works:

```
SELECT 
    b.description, a.date,
FROM 
    a 
JOIN 
    b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE 
    a.date >= '2014-01-01'
    AND b.date <= '2019-07-31'
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database engine you're using. `sql` is a language, not a database product. Did you mean `sql-server`?

Comment: Oh, of course! My apologies. I'm using AWS.

Comment: What database engine in AWS?

Comment: Which data type is the column `b.description`?

Comment: It should be a string. The remainder are integer (other than date, which is date). (Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

Without a sample data is hard to guess where is the problem, because the query seem fine. My suggestion is start with a basic working query and start adding things until you found what is causing the error. When you found it edits your question and give us more info.

Start with:

```
SELECT  
    a.date,
    b.description,
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    a 
JOIN 
    b ON a.id = b.id
GROUP BY 
    a.date, b.description
```

Then add the `WHERE` conditions one by one, then the `SUM` one by one, etc

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work! It looks like the problem is an error in Redshift that can make integers load as varchars (when they should be integers). This blog has more about it:
 https://blog.getdbt.com/how-to-safely-convert-strings-to-integers-in-redshift/

Honestly now unsure why some of the earlier queries worked, but life is mysterious…

I solved my query by changing it to this:

```
SELECT b.description as description, a. date as date,

SUM(CASE WHEN a.int1 ~ '^[0-9]+$' THEN a.int1 ELSE null end::int) as int1,

SUM(CASE WHEN a.int2 ~ '^[0-9]+$' THEN a.int2 ELSE null end::int) as int2,

SUM(CASE WHEN a.int3 ~ '^[0-9]+$' THEN a.int3 ELSE null end::int) as int3,

SUM(CASE WHEN a.int4 ~ '^[0-9]+$' THEN a.int4 ELSE null end::int) as int4,

SUM(CASE WHEN a.int5 ~ '^[0-9]+$' THEN a.int5 ELSE null end::int) as int5

FROM a JOIN b

ON a.id = b.id

WHERE a.date >= '2014-01-01'

AND b.date <= '2019-07-31'

GROUP BY b.description, a. date
```

Comment: Glad you solve it, but you shouldn't use var char to save `secs`. And fyi `ELSE NULL` is the default so no need to include the `ELSE` and can simplify the query.